# How to edit menu list on muktiboot usb flash drive

Tags: usb, multi-boot, grub, bootloader

I used this [guide here][1] to create a multiboot usb:

The code below is found in the `menu.lst` file on the flash drive. How do I edit to remove the unwanted items, eg Tiny Core:

```
# This Menu Created by Lance http://www.pendrivelinux.com
# Ongoing Suggested Menu Entries and the Suggestor are noted!
default 0
timeout 30
root=(hd0,0)
color NORMAL HIGHLIGHT HELPTEXT HEADING
splashimage=(hd0,0)/splash.xpm.gz
foreground=FFFFFF
background=0066FF 

title Memtest86+
find --set-root /mt410.iso
map --mem /mt410.iso (hd32)
map --hook
root (hd32)
chainloader (hd32)

# Suggested by madprofessor
title Boot Clonezilla
root (hd0,0)
kernel /clonezilla/live/vmlinuz live-media-path=clonezilla/live bootfrom=/dev/sd boot=live union=aufs noprompt ocs_live_run="ocs-live-general" ocs_live_extra_param="" ocs_live_keymap="" ocs_live_batch="no" ocs_lang="" vga=791 ip=frommedia
initrd /clonezilla/live/initrd.img

# Suggested by Ross Holley
title Boot gparted (Partition Tools)
root (hd0,0)
kernel /gparted/live/vmlinuz live-media-path=gparted/live bootfrom=/dev/sd boot=live union=aufs noswap noprompt ip=frommedia
initrd /gparted/live/initrd.img

title Parted Magic 4.11 (Partition Tools)
find --set-root /pmagic-4.11.iso
map /pmagic-4.11.iso (hd32)
map --hook
root (hd32)
chainloader (hd32)

# Suggested by Deb
title Partition Wizard 5 (Partition Tools)
find --set-root /pwhe5.iso
map /pwhe5.iso (hd32)
map --hook
root (hd32)
chainloader (hd32)

title Balder DOS image (FreeDOS)
map --unsafe-boot /balder10.img (fd0)
map --hook
chainloader --force (fd0)+1
rootnoverify (fd0)

title Redo Backup and Recovery
find --set-root --ignore-floppies --ignore-cd /redobackup-0.9.2.iso
map --heads=0 --sectors-per-track=0 /redobackup-0.9.2.iso (hd32)
map --hook
chainloader (hd32)

title Linux Mint 9
find --set-root /linuxmint-9-gnome-cd-i386.iso
map /linuxmint-9-gnome-cd-i386.iso (0xff)
map --hook
root (0xff)
kernel /casper/vmlinuz file=/cdrom/preseed/mint.seed boot=casper persistent iso-scan/filename=/linuxmint-9-gnome-cd-i386.iso splash
initrd /casper/initrd.lz

# Suggested by Szymon Silski
title Linux Mint 8
find --set-root /LinuxMint-8.iso
map /LinuxMint-8.iso (0xff)
map --hook
root (0xff)
kernel /casper/vmlinuz file=/cdrom/preseed/mint.seed boot=casper persistent iso-scan/filename=/LinuxMint-8.iso splash
initrd /casper/initrd.lz

title Ubuntu 10.04
find --set-root /ubuntu-10.04-desktop-i386.iso
map /ubuntu-10.04-desktop-i386.iso (0xff)
map --hook
root (0xff)
kernel /casper/vmlinuz file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper persistent iso-scan/filename=/ubuntu-10.04-desktop-i386.iso splash
initrd /casper/initrd.lz

title Xubuntu 10.04 (XFCE Desktop)
find --set-root /xubuntu-10.04-desktop-i386.iso
map /xubuntu-10.04-desktop-i386.iso (0xff)
map --hook
root (0xff)
kernel /casper/vmlinuz file=/cdrom/preseed/xubuntu.seed boot=casper persistent iso-scan/filename=/xubuntu-10.04-desktop-i386.iso splash
initrd /casper/initrd.lz

title Kubuntu 10.04 (KDE Desktop)
find --set-root /kubuntu-10.04-desktop-i386.iso
map /kubuntu-10.04-desktop-i386.iso (0xff)
map --hook
root (0xff)
kernel /casper/vmlinuz file=/cdrom/preseed/kubuntu.seed boot=casper persistent iso-scan/filename=/kubuntu-10.04-desktop-i386.iso splash
initrd /casper/initrd.lz

# Suggested by Ambriel
title Lubuntu 10.04 (LXDE Lightweight Desktop)
find --set-root /lubuntu-10.04.iso
map /lubuntu-10.04.iso (0xff)
map --hook
root (0xff)
kernel /casper/vmlinuz file=/cdrom/preseed/lubuntu.seed boot=casper persist
```

Comment: Oh dear Jesus Lord MY EYES! What is this?

Comment: 1. Please use the code blocks to wrap such text 2. How do we know what is "unwanted" for you, without further info ?

Answer (score 1):

That's just GRUB Legacy. Remove everything from the `title` you want to remove all the way to, but not including, the next `title`.